# android_alarm_manager_plus: ^2.0.3 not working [FLUTTER]

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I have a problem with [android_alarm_manager_plus: ^2.0.3](https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager_plus) library on flutter.
I tried to use it as in the document it worked for one time when I use periodic method here is the code :

```
import 'package:android_alarm_manager_plus/android_alarm_manager_plus.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';

main() async {
  // Be sure to add this line if initialize() call happens before runApp()
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await AndroidAlarmManager.initialize();
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));
  const int helloAlarmID = 0;
  await AndroidAlarmManager.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 5), 1, printHello,
      wakeup: true, exact: true);
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold();
  }
}

void printHello() {
  Fluttertoast.showToast(
      msg: "This is Center Short Toast",
      toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
      gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
      timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      textColor: Colors.white,
      fontSize: 16.0);
}
```

and I added these permissions to manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<!-- For apps with targetSDK=31 (Android 12) -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM"/>
```

and these serveses:

```
<service
    android:name="dev.fluttercommunity.plus.androidalarmmanager.AlarmService"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
    android:exported="false"/>
<receiver
    android:name="dev.fluttercommunity.plus.androidalarmmanager.AlarmBroadcastReceiver"
    android:exported="false"/>
<receiver
    android:name="dev.fluttercommunity.plus.androidalarmmanager.RebootBroadcastReceiver"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

the toast message appeared one time after 5 m then it will not appear! :(

Comment: Try it in release mode

Comment: I downloaded the example code for android_alarm_manager_plus from github and I'm happy to say it works, because I tried very hard to write my own code and was never able to get it working